# Does PostgreSQL always initialize database of same size?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I run `CREATE DATABASE abcd`, PostgreSQL will create an empty database and if I run `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('abcd'));`, I get size of the database, let's say 8000kB. What I want to know is will the size of the empty database always be the same no matter what or does it depend? I specifically need to know if empty database size would change over time (create database 1 year from now) or if it would change over quantity (10000th database). I can't test for those cases and I couldn't find any information on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. The database is formed from the contents of `template1` a "master database." Adding things to `template1` will directly affect the contents of the new database.

From the docs, [Template Databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

> **CREATE DATABASE actually works by copying an existing database. By default, it copies the standard system database named `template1`. Thus that database is the "template" from which new databases are made. If you add objects to `template1`, these objects will be copied into subsequently created user databases.** This behavior allows site-local modifications to the standard set of objects in databases. For example, if you install the procedural language PL/Perl in `template1`, it will automatically be available in user databases without any extra action being taken when those databases are created.

However, you can create a *copy* of `template0` which we hope is a virgin database, also from the docs links above.

> There is a second standard system database named `template0`. This database contains the same data as the initial contents of `template1`, that is, only the standard objects predefined by your version of PostgreSQL. `template0` should never be changed after the database cluster has been initialized. **By instructing `CREATE DATABASE` to copy `template0` instead of `template1`, you can create a "virgin" user database that contains none of the site-local additions in `template1`.** This is particularly handy when restoring a pg_dump dump: the dump script should be restored in a virgin database to ensure that one recreates the correct contents of the dumped database, without conflicting with objects that might have been added to `template1` later on
>
> Another common reason for copying `template0` instead of `template1` is that new encoding and locale settings can be specified when copying `template0`, whereas a copy of `template1` must use the same settings it does. This is because `template1` might contain encoding-specific or locale-specific data, while `template0` is known not to.
>
> To create a database by copying template0, use:
>
> ```
> CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0;
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read through the link you provided. However, now that we know how DB is created, I must ask does the system ever modify the template1 database by itself? I suppose not since I can't find anything about that on Google, but better be sure.

Comment: No, however as the docs say it's not guaranteed to be the same. Users often modify it, and shared providers tend to implement supported extensions to Pg with it too.